# Populating multiple cells in row from a reference table, depending on single cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to populate columns D-J of table1, with the values in table2, columns B-H. The values should be based upon the value of column C in table1.

I have the code below, but I believe that is copying the tables as is and not doing a check of the value in column C.

Images:
[image: table1] [image: table2]

```vb
Sub wps()

Dim rng As Range
Dim strTable As String
Dim strAddress As String
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Procedures")

    For i = 1 To .ListObjects.Count
        strTable = .ListObjects(i).Name
        Set rng = .ListObjects(strTable).Range
        strAddress = rng.Cells(2, 3).Address
        rng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Base Data").Range(strAddress)
        With Worksheets("Base Data")
            .ListObjects(i).Name = "quals"
        End With
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There there a reason you are not using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: What is it you're doing with the tables? Why are you looping? Why are you renaming? Please add those and more clarifications to your question.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad You're absolutely right, this was the simplest way, didn't thin it would have worked, but it does perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `destination.value=source.value` situation, using a single `Match()`.  You could wrap this in a loop on your `destWS`.

Maybe something like (mock-up, untested):

```
For i = 2 to lastRowDest
    dim sourceWS as worksheet
    set sourceWS = sheets(1)
    dim destWS as worksheet
    set destWS = sheets(2)

    destinationSearchTerm = destWS.Cells(i,"C").Value
    
    dim sourceRow as long
    sourceRow =     Application.Match(destinationSearchTerm, sourceWS.Columns("A"), 0)

    destWS.Range(destWS.Cells(i,"D"), destWS.Cells(i,"J") = sourceWS.Range(sourceWS.Cells(sourceRow,"B"),sourceWS.Cells(sourceRow,"H")
Next i
```